# PHP cURL post of an XML - Premature end of file

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am submitting an XML post request to a URL and need to parse the response back. However, I'm constantly getting `Premature end of file` error.

Here is my entire code:

```
$xml_data =
'<ndxml>' .
'<header>' . 
    '<credentials>' .
        '<identity>user</identity>' .
        '<password>pass</password>' .
    '</credentials>' .
'</header>' .
'<request>' .
    '<gettrackrequest uniqueref="" consignment="1111" postalCode="" reference=""> </gettrackrequest>' .
'</request>' .
'</ndxml>';

$URL = "http://xmlapi.emea.api/xmlsubmit.php3";

function sendPostRequestToNetDespatch($URL, $xml_data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //return curl_error($ch);
    return $result;
}


$output = sendPostRequestToNetDespatch($URL, $xml_data);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($output) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

My response is `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [response] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [status] => Premature end of file. ) )`

Comment: It depends on what the content of `$output` is (the result from the curl request). Looks like the problem is not in this part of the code.

Comment: That's what confuses me - it should be a big XML response. But I get this error - it's the same error that shows when I access the `$URL` directly in my browser. On the testing API the response is fine, on the live it fails.

Comment: Are you in control of the code at `http://xmlapi.emea.api/xmlsubmit.php3` ? If not then there's not much you can do but report it. If you are then do share that code since that's the part that seems to be problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not. OK - I'll post an update when I hear back. Thanks @apokryfos

Comment: Actually now that I take a second look at it, ` curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);` may not be what you need to do there. It may need some sort of `"varname=".$xml_data` there. Depends on the API spec

Comment: Either the server is not willing to respond, or unable at the moment, it might relate to the request that you send or not - you could take a network trace with wireshark to try to see more detail about the http level communication.

Comment: @apokryfos - there is no official docs for this api so I'll have to wait to hear back from them.

Comment: @StefanHegny - sorry, not familiar enough with wireshark to be able to use it. Thanks anyway

Comment: By the way is this relevant to https://emea.netdespatch.com/xml/reqform.html ? Looks like an XML checker.

Comment: yes, that is the test API form - checks the XML - it works on that but not on live @apokryfos